# Why is one thread faster than just calling a function, mingw

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, function, mingw

When I call function execution time is 6.8 sec.
Call it from a thread time is 3.4 sec 
and when using 2 thread 1.8 sec. No matter what optimization I use rations stay same.

In Visual Studio times are like expected 3.1, 3 and 1.7 sec.

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 400

float a[N][N];

struct b{
    int begin;
    int end;
};

DWORD WINAPI thread(LPVOID p)
{
    b b_t = *(b*)p;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int j=b_t.begin;j<b_t.end;j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
                a[i][j]+=k*sin(j)-j*cos(k);
        }

    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    clock_t t;
    HANDLE hn[2];

    b b_t[3];

    b_t[0].begin = 0;
    b_t[0].end = N;

    b_t[1].begin = 0;
    b_t[1].end = N/2;

    b_t[2].begin = N/2;
    b_t[2].end = N;

    t = clock();
    thread(&b_t[0]);
    printf("0 - %d\n",clock()-t);

    t = clock();
    hn[0] = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, thread,  &b_t[0], 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hn[0], INFINITE );
    printf("1 - %d\n",clock()-t);

    t = clock();
    hn[0] = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, thread,  &b_t[1], 0, NULL);
    hn[1] = CreateThread ( NULL, 0, thread,  &b_t[2], 0, NULL);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hn, TRUE, INFINITE );
    printf("2 - %d\n",clock()-t);

    return 0;
}
```

Times:

```
0 - 6868
1 - 3362
2 - 1827
```

CPU - Core 2 Duo T9300

OS - Windows 8, 64 - bit

compiler: mingw32-g++.exe, gcc version 4.6.2

edit:

Tried different order, same result, even tried separate applications.
Task Manager showing CPU Utilization around 50% for function and 1 thread and 100% for 2 thread

Sum of all elements after each call is the same: 3189909.237955

Cygwin result: 2.5, 2.5 and 2.5 sec
Linux result(pthread):  3.7, 3.7 and 2.1 sec

@borisbn results: 0 - 1446 1 - 1439 2 - 721.

Comment: I can feel Mysticial typing...

Comment: Could you post numbers for running the function again the same way (i.e. not in a thread)? You're probably pulling all of the array 'a' into cache for a start.

Comment: @SethCarnegie ... and I thought I was the only one..=P

Comment: @SethCarnegie Nah... I can't spot the problem at a glance and I don't have mingw32 installed.

Comment: Yes, try a different order, and see if that makes a difference. I bet "the first time" takes longer, rather than the thread vs no thread.

Comment: Although I somewhat doubt this has to do with cold cache of the data. The computation is `O(N^2)` - which would dwarf the time needed to warm the cache anyways.

Comment: Has someone got a good working number for cycles in a cache miss? I'm used to working with fixed numbers on in-order consoles :) and prefetching would make a big difference with this code. Also, the array is threaded by splitting vertically into two halves of 200 columns each. I'd be splitting horizontally i.e. change begin and end to determine the start and end values of i, not j.

Comment: Well, I haven't got a windows VM running at the moment, and it's late, so I'm not going to play with it. Could be CPU affinity or some such as well.

Comment: g++ (TDM) 4.7.1 gives `0 - 1388  1 - 1388  2 - 796` for me as expected.

Comment: MinGW 4.6.2. Exactly your code. Compile options: -O2. Results: `0 - 1446 1 - 1439 2 - 721`. The same results with `std::thread`. I tried to run thread before function call, I moved `float a[N][N];` inside `struct b` - the result didn't change

Comment: So it's not compiler, could it be OS?  @borisbn

Comment: @user1978768 here is an exe-file, compiled by my mingw from your code - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46469564/a.exe

Comment: 0 - 1615, 1 - 1864, 2 - 1007

Comment: @user1978768, as you see, there's no OS's problem. I've got WinGW [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/). Another difference is that my host and compilation target platforms are 32-bit, but yours one is 64... hmmm... need to think more )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is a result of something in the math library implementing `sin()` and `cos()` - if you replace the calls to those functions with something else that takes time the significant difference between step and 0 and step 1 goes away.

Note that I see the difference with `gcc (tdm-1) 4.6.1`, which is a 32-bit toolchain targeting 32 bit binaries. Optimization makes no difference (not surprising since it seems to be something in the math library).

However, if I build using `gcc (tdm64-1) 4.6.1`, which is a 64-bit toolchain, the difference does *not* appear - regardless if the build is creating a 32-bit program (using the `-m32` option) or a 64-bit program (`-m64`).

Here are some example test runs (I made minor modifications to the source to make it C99 compatible):

- Using the 32-bit TDM MinGW 4.6.1 compiler:

  ```
  C:\temp>gcc --version
  gcc (tdm-1) 4.6.1

  C:\temp>gcc -m32 -std=gnu99 -o test.exe test.c

  C:\temp>test
  0 - 4082
  1 - 2439
  2 - 1238
  ```
- Using the 64-bit TDM 4.6.1 compiler:

  ```
  C:\temp>gcc --version
  gcc (tdm64-1) 4.6.1

  C:\temp>gcc -m32 -std=gnu99 -o test.exe test.c

  C:\temp>test
  0 - 2506
  1 - 2476
  2 - 1254

  C:\temp>gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -o test.exe test.c

  C:\temp>test
  0 - 3031
  1 - 3031
  2 - 1539
  ```

A little more information:

The 32-bit TDM distribution (gcc (tdm-1) 4.6.1) links to the `sin()`/`cos()` implementations in the `msvcrt.dll` system DLL via a provided import library:

```
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libmsvcrt.a(dcfls00599.o)
                0x004a113c                _imp__cos
```

While the 64-bit distribution (gcc (tdm64-1) 4.6.1) doesn't appear to do that, instead linking to some static library implementation provided with the distribution:

```
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib32/libmingwex.a(lib32_libmingwex_a-cos.o)
                              C:\Users\mikeb\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3pk20i.o (cos)
```

---

**Update/Conclusion:**

After a bit of spelunking in a debugger stepping through the assembly of `msvcrt.dll`'s implementation of `cos()` I've found that the difference in the timing of the main thread versus an explicitly created thread  is due to the FPU's precision being set to a non-default setting (presumably the MinGW runtime in question does this at start up).  In the situation where the `thread()` function takes twice as long, the FPU is set to 64-bit precision (`REAL10` or in MSVC-speak `_PC_64`). When the FPU control word is something other than 0x27f (the default state?), the `msvcrt.dll` runtime will perform the following steps in the `sin()` and `cos()` function (and probably other floating point functions):

- save the current FPU control word
- set the FPU control word to 0x27f (I believe it's possible for this value to be modified)
- perform the `fsin`/`fcos` operation
- restore the saved FPU control word

The save/restore of the FPU control word is skipped if it's already set to the expected/desired 0x27f value. Apparently saving/restoring the FPU control word is expensive, since it appears to double the amount of time the function takes.

You can solve the problem by adding the following line to `main()` before calling `thread()`:

```
_control87( _PC_53, _MCW_PC);   // requires <float.h>
```

Comment: The answer has been updated with a more precise culprit to the problem.

Comment: +1 very nicely worked out. But what could be the purpose for MinGW to have these weird settings, to let 'main thread' and 'user created threads` have a different FPU precision?

Comment: @Arno: I don't know why some MinGW builds set the FP precision to 64-bit. And as far as the precision setting for created threads - that's a Windows detail of not 'inheriting' the FP precision when a thread is created - MinGW's library isn't involved in `CreateThread()`. And It seems to me to be a bug in `msvcrt.dll` to *reduce* the precision when performing the `fcos`/`fsin` operation (I imagine the safe/modify/restore precision logic was intended to make sure the operation wasn't done with the FPU set to single precision).

Answer (score 2):

Not a `cache matter`here.

Likely different runtime libraries for user created threads and main thread.
You may compare the calculations `a[i][j]+=k*sin(j)-j*cos(k);` in detail (numbers) for specific values of i, j, and k to confirm differences.

Comment: Sum of all elements after each call is the same: 3189909.237955

Comment: Pls. checkout the RTL selection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and verify which one you are using. MinGW defines [MSVCRT_VERSION"](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/mingw/2009-March/000957.html).

Comment: # define __MSVCRT_VERSION__ 0x0600

Comment: seeing that you accepted the answer telling that you're facing a library problem which was my initial thought, I'd suggest to compile with -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0601 since you're running Windows 8

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the main thread is doing 64 bit float math and the threads are doing 53 bit math.

You can know this / fix it by changing the code to

```
...
extern "C" unsigned int _control87( unsigned int newv, unsigned int mask );

DWORD WINAPI thread(LPVOID p)
{
    printf( "_control87(): 0x%.4x\n", _control87( 0, 0 ) );
    _control87(0x00010000,0x00010000);
...
```

The output will be:

```
c:\temp>test   
_control87(): 0x8001f
0 - 2667
_control87(): 0x9001f
1 - 2683
_control87(): 0x9001f
_control87(): 0x9001f
2 - 1373

c:\temp>mingw32-c++ --version
mingw32-c++ (GCC) 4.6.2
```

You can see that 0 was going to run w/o the 0x10000 flag, but once set, runs at the same speed as 1 & 2.  If you look up the [`_control87()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function, you'll see that this value is the _PC_53 flag, which sets the precision to be 53 instead of 64 had it been left as zero.

For some reason, Mingw isn't setting it to the same value at process init time that  CreateThread() does at thread create time.

Another work around it to turn on SSE2 with [`_set_SSE2_enable(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bthd138d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which will run even faster, but may give different results.

```
c:\temp>test   
0 - 1341
1 - 1326
2 - 702
```

I believe this is on by default for the 64 bit because all 64 bit processors support SSE2.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, change the order of your three tests to get some more insight. Also, the fact that you have a multi-core machine pretty well explains why using two threads doing half the work each takes half the time. Take a look at your CPU usage monitor (Control-Shift-Escape) to find out how many cores are maxed out during the running time.

Comment: Tried different order, same result, even tried separate applications.
Task Manager showing CPU Utilization around 50% for function and 1 thread and 100% for 2 thread